# C++ expression must be a modifiable value

Tags: c++, struct, directx, expression, structure

```
struct PLANE {FLOAT X, Y, Z; D3DXVECTOR3 Normal; FLOAT U, V;};

class PlaneStruct
{
public:PLANE PlaneVertices[4];
public:DWORD PlaneIndices;

void CreatePlane(float size)
{
    // create vertices to represent the corners of the cube
    PlaneVertices = 
    {
        {1.0f * size, 0.0f, 1.0f * size, D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), 0.0f, 0.0f},    // side 1
        {-1.0f * size, -0.0f, 1.0f * size, D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), 0.0f, 1.0f},
        {-1.0f * size, -0.0f, -1.0f * size, D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), 1.0f, 0.0f},
        {1.0f * size, -0.0f, -1.0f * size, D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), 1.0f, 1.0f},
    };

    // create the index buffer out of DWORDs
    DWORD PlaneIndices[] =
    {
        0, 2, 1,    // side 1
        0, 3, 2
    };
}
};
```

This was my code for a "plane" structure, i just have one question, if you look at the top it says PLANE PlaneVertices[4]; and then in a function i wanted to define it, so to give it specific values, but i get the following error:
    Expression must be a modifiable value.
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign values to your `PlaneVertices` array like this, you can only use this when you define it using the {} notation to initialise it. Try assigning each element to each invidivual element of your array using a for loop

Edit: In response to your comment, create an instance of your PLANE struct and assign the values to it that you want it to have. Then assign this to the first index in the `PlaneVertices` array using

```
    PlaneVertices[0] = // instance of PLANE struct you have just created
```

then repeat for the remaining 3 instances of PLANE that you want in the array, adding to the 1,2,and 3 indices of `PlaneVertices`. To fully illustrate I will do the first one for you using your data provided

```
    PLANE plane_object;
    plane_object.X = 1.0*size;
    plane_object.Y = 0.0; 
    plane_object.Z = 1.0*size; 
    plane_object.Normal = D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    plane_object.U = 0.0;
    plane_object.V = 0.0;
    PlaneVertices[0] = plane_object;
```

You then need to repeat for each PLANE you want to add. Also take not of the other answer concerning your PlaneIndices problem.

Comment: I see what you are trying to say, but i have no idea how to impliment it as i have never used this method, so i would like to ask you an example, and then i can further develop it.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ (2003) initialization, like `StructX var = { ... };` Can be used only when you define a variable. In your code PlaneVertices is used in an assignment expression. Initialization syntax is not allowed there. This is a syntax error.

Later on you define a local variable PlaneIndices that will be discarded after the exit from the  method.

Comment: I will apply the same method as(when i get it fixed) from the PlaneVertices to the Indices, but how can i then give PlaneVertices these loads of values?

Comment: PlaneIndices is defined as a number in a class and as array inside the method. This is not the same thing. From your code it is not clear what you need/want.